# Google Chrome Stack Exchange URL Escaper Extension?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I'm looking for something to take a link like

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(object-oriented_design)

And make it into

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29

so that it can be pasted into a comment automatically. Even better would be if said extension could do the replacement whenever I paste anything into a stack exchange site that looks like a URL.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than look up the HTML entities for _, (, and ), I just modify the URL to include a backslash before each. To use your example, I take:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(object-oriented_design)
```

and turn it into:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid\_\(object-oriented\_design\)
```

Then use that twice; once inside square brackets, and once inside parenthesis<sup>*</sup>:

`[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid\_\(object-oriented\_design\)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid\_\(object-oriented\_design\))`

which then becomes:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(object-oriented_design)

It's a little convoluted, but I don't have to recall specific entities, run an extension, or do anything that doesn't work cross-browser.

<sub><sup>*</sup> Preview makes it look as if you don't need this step—but if you skip it, the link in your post won't work.</sub>

Comment: Test: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid\_\(object-oriented\_design\)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid\_\(object-oriented\_design\))

Comment: @Billy - looks like a successful test to me.

Comment: +1 because this makes it easier, but I'm still looking for an extension that can do it.

Comment: @Billy - it would be easy enough to write a bookmarklet; let me know if you need one. And if you don't get an answer with an extension, please accept this one.

Comment: Will do lol.

Answer (score 1):

I've built a simple [Ubiquity](http://mozillalabs.com/ubiquity/) (not Chrome, but it is useful to post it here I suppose) command to do this.

> **[Install](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1722364/Stack%20Overflow/ubiq.html) - [Source](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1722364/Stack%20Overflow/ubiq_encode.js)**
>   <sub>(Non-Ubiquity using users will just see a blank page)</sub>
>
> **Name:** `encode` or `url encode`

The code is very simple, as JavaScript has it's own [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) function, but WMD is a little more strict about what you can put in there - `( ) :` are also encoded. If I missed anything just drop a comment here.

```
var protocol = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('://') + 3)
return protocol + encodeURI(url).substring(url.indexOf('://') + 3).replace(/\(/g, '%28').replace(/\)/g, '%29%').replace(/:/g, '%3A');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used [bit.ly](http://bit.ly/) to shorten the link and got it working.

Anyway I agree that there should be a better way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JavaScript's `escape()` function.

```
(function() {
    alert(escape(prompt('URL to escape:')));
})();
```

Bookmarklet format:

```
(function(){alert(escape(prompt('URL to escape:')));})();
```