# Link ending with ) is not enclosed in anchor tag correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

Just added a comment to a question that contained a link to the Scrum_(development) page at Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(development). Unfortunately, the closing `)` was not included in the link and it's now broken. I tried editing the comment to see if it was an EOL issue, but it's not. Any link which ends with a `)` is not wrapped in an appropriate anchor tag.

The comment in question can be found on [Steven A. Lowe's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36562/how-do-you-deal-with-design-in-scrum/36584#36584) on Programmers.SE.

**Update**
Looks like the anchor wrapping issue applies to all SE text input boxes as this bug reports link to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(development) is broken as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Links to URLs containing parentheses](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses)

Comment: Also (to a degree) a dupe of [Google Chrome Stack Exchange URL Escaper Extension?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72386/google-chrome-stack-exchange-url-escaper-extension/).

Comment: I'm not sure this is a dupe; wasn't the parenthesis-handling behavior changed in the past few days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very much by design. Since this case:

> `As I said elsewhere (see http://my-ramblings.com/42) you're wrong.`

is very common, a closing paren is considered ending a automatically detected link.* So when you have that character in the link, you can't rely on auto-linking anymore; you'll have to explicitly tell the system where your link starts and where it ends.

> `See the [Wikipedia page on Scrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(development)) for details.`

* <sub>The rules are a little more subtle; if the paren is within the URL, it might actually work. Bottom line: don't rely on it.</sub>

### Update:

See [URL detecting error with address like "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66472/url-detecting-error-with-address-like-http-en-wikipedia-org-wiki-octet-compu/165064#165064) for details; long story short: After the next build of the site, this will work as you had expected.